# An equivalence for $\operatorname{grade}(I,M)\ge 2$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, noetherian

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $M$ a finite $R$-module and $I$ an ideal of $R$. Show that $\operatorname{grade}(I,M)\ge 2$ iff the canonical homomorphism $M \mapsto\operatorname{Hom}_R(I,M)$ is an isomorphism.

This question is Exercise 1.2.24 in the book: Winfried Bruns and Jürgen Herzog, *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*, Cambridge University Press, 1998.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the exact sequence $$0\to \operatorname{Ext}^{0}(R/I, M) \to M\to \operatorname{Hom}_R(I,M)\to \operatorname{Ext}^1(R/I,M)\to 0$$ and Theorem 1.2.5(Rees) (this is usually taken as the definition of grade), p.10 of the same book you mention.

Comment: +1 I tried solving this problem explicitly, e.g. if $grade(I,M) \ge 2$ i tried to show that $M \rightarrow Hom(I,M)$ is both injective and surjective. The injectivity follows easily but the surjectivity seemed hard. Any comments on that?

Comment: @Manos, then by definition of grade, both $\operatorname{Ext}^i(R/I, M)=0$ for $i=0,1$.

Comment: I understand your argument and the proof, but what i meant is that i tried to show that if $grade(I,M) \ge 2$ and $f \in Hom(I,M)$, then there exists $x_f \in M$ such that for every $a \in I$ we have $f(a) = a x_f$. That's what i mean by "explicitly".

Comment: @user114539 How about the case IM=M, we can not use the Theorem 1.2.5(Rees), how to prove the surjection in the right side?